# SQL / MYSQL query not executing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql / mysql query to execute but I get errors. I wonder maybe you can spot it/them. I have a table filled with data(picture attached.[image])

And my query is:

```
select Food, tbl_Date
from finance.fin
where if (day(now()) > 10,
    (select Food, tbl_Date
    where tbl_Date between concat(year(now()), "-", month(now()), "-", 10)  and curdate()),
    (select Food, tbl_Date
    where tbl_Date BETWEEN concat(year(now()), "-", month(now())-1, "-", 10)
AND CURDATE()));
```

I want to check if today's day is > 10 and then if true -> select food and tbl_Date rows between dates of this month 10th and current day; else I want to select rows from food and tbl_Date where dates are between last months 10th and current day.

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where tbl_Date between concat(year(now()), "-", month(now()), "-", 10) and curd' at line 2
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Screenshots are almost always completely irrelevant and clutter up your question. A properly formatted query and, if necessary, the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for relevant tables helps considerably.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I will try to learn from them. The query I am struggling with is pretty simple. A more experienced developer would spot the bug instantly I suppose.

Comment: Well, that comment will surely get a better response from all participants.

Comment: That select is messed up you are missing the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT f.Food
     , f.tbl_Date
  FROM finance.fin f
 WHERE f.tbl_Date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-10') 
                     + INTERVAL IF(DAY(NOW())>10,0,-1) MONTH
   AND f.tbl_Date <= CURDATE()
```

The syntax error is a missing FROM clause, you've got a SELECT with a WHERE. But even if you fix that, there's another problem, in the given context, the subquery can return a single scalar, one expression and one row.

You've also got a problem with date arithmetic, subtracting 1 from the integer value of the month is a problem in January... you'll get a zero for the month, where what you really want is to subtract 1 from the year and set the month to 12. Make use of MySQL's builtin date arithmetic instead, and subtract an interval of one month.

You can push that conditional check deeper, and just return either a 0 or a -1. That's the only part of the query that needs to change.
The query above gives you a result like this:

On the 11th of the month, e.g. '2014-12-11', the query would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT f.Food
     , f.tbl_Date
  FROM finance.fin f
 WHERE f.tbl_Date >= '2014-12-10' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
   AND f.tbl_Date <= '2014-12-11'
```

On the 9th of the month, e.g. '2014-12-09' the query would be equivalent to

```
SELECT f.Food
     , f.tbl_Date
  FROM finance.fin f
 WHERE f.tbl_Date >= '2014-12-10' + INTERVAL -1 MONTH
   AND f.tbl_Date <= '2014-12-09'
```

(This assumes the data type of the `tbl_Date` column is `DATE` and you are wanting to do "date" comparisons.)

For DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP comparisons, I typically use a pattern like this:

```
  WHERE t.dt >= lower_bound
    AND t.dt <  upper_bound
```

with the `upper_bound` being the lowest datetime value that I *don't* want included; in this case, midnight of the following day. This pattern "works" for any precision of the `dt` column, whether that's just a DATE, or whether that it's getting all times of the day up to `23:59:59 (or up to the more precise`23:59:59.997`, in the case of SQL Server.) I follow this same convention when the resolution is only to the day, because this same pattern works.

So, I'd actually be inclined to write it like this:

```
 WHERE f.tbl_Date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-10') 
                     + INTERVAL IF(DAY(NOW())>10,0,-1) MONTH
   AND f.tbl_Date <  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note that this is doing a less than comparison (without the equal) to midnight of the following day. That's how we'd want to write it if `tbl_Date` was of datatype `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, rather than `DATE`.

Comment: It's pretty strange that I am not encouraged to say 'thanks' in comments for such a great job you have done, spencer7593. I thank you very much! :) also since I don't want my comment to be deleted, there is a syntax error in you query. One parenthesis is missing in IF clause: IF(DAY(NOW()>10,0,-1). Thank you, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to judge your date arithmetic, just to fix the problem with the query.  When used in a query, `if()` is a function, used primarily in the `select`, `where`, and `on` clauses.  It is not control flow.  The logic you want is more like:

```
select Food, tbl_Date
from finance.fin
where (day(now()) > 10 and
       tbl_Date between concat(year(now()), "-", month(now()), "-", 10)  and curdate()
      ) or
      (day(now()) <= 10) and
       tbl_Date BETWEEN concat(year(now()), "-", month(now())-1, "-", 10) and curdate()
     )
```

Comment: Why not use `DATE_FORMAT( '%Y-%m-10')` and then add either (based on the condition) an interval of `0` or `-1` months? Subtracting 1 from the integer month value just seems wrong, in January, 1-1 = 0.